# Grub update can't detect hybernating Windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've kinda wound myself into some weird paradox.

I have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed on two different HDs. Both are 64 bit. I just recently deleted and reinstalled Ubuntu, but `update-grub` and `os-prober` can't find my windows partition. I thought maybe it was damaged so I ran `ntfsfix /dev/sda2` (where Windows is installed) and got the error `Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.`

I've already tried going into my BIOS/UEFI settings on my motherboard, but my motherboard doesn't detect the drive anymore either. I can still see the drive when I run `gdisk` or `gparted`. I tried boot-repair, but that actually made ubuntu completely unbootable. I had to chroot from my live USB and reinstall Grub2 so I could even ask this question. So all this together leaves me in between a rock and a hard place.

How do I boot into Windows to unhibernate Windows so grub2 can detect Windows and add Windows as a bootable option in grub?

Answer (score 0):

Use your windows 8 disc and do Automatic Repair. This will solve your windows problem. Then use ubuntu's boot repair disc to solve dual boot problem.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-the-windows-8-automatic-repair-feature-works/